# Could someone suggest a good book for a first course in real analysis for someone who just failed their first course in real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Okay so basically I've never taken a course that involved any proof writing (other than having done proof by induction in a levels) until my first real analysis course and I did really, really bad in it. We were using Bartle's introduction to real analysis, but I honestly never really understood the proofs in it, or how to write my own. I need to retake the course, but I want to figure out how to do it myself in the first place. Any leads on how to start would be really really appreciated. Also, if there is anything I need to do to make it easier for me to understand, please suggest that as well.

Thank youu!!!

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655443/what-are-some-good-introductory-books-on-mathematical-proofs), and consider *How to Prove It* by Velleman

Comment: That's rather odd. A typical high school curriculum involves basic algebraic identities like $(a+b) ^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and these are usually proved in textbook. Another key area where proofs are presented is geometry. Thus most high schools are expected to know the proofx that sum of all angles of a triangle add up to two right angles. Easier proofs in analysis involve a clear understanding of definitions and some idea of order relations. So this is not much different. The difficult/long proofs will take some time and one should not get discouraged by them.

Comment: Ah yes I mean, I've done super basic proofs and I understand the ones at a high school level, but I meant at a university level, I havent done anything that focuses solely on proof writing, and I dont get the intuition behind a lot of statements/questions that we have to prove. The definitions don't make a lot of sense either, especially when it gets to delta-epsilon proofs for limits/sequences/series and everything else that needs them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to try "How to think about Analysis" by Lara Alcock. It will give you a chance to think about the subject as a whole rather than trying to start again at a course you have found tough. She is a BRILLIANT teacher.  Give it a go.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! I will definitely check it out, and hopefully it will help me understand analysis more lol