# Reference Request for Real Analysis/Proofwriting

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I'm looking to learn real analysis however I'm unsure of where to start having little proof background. I would also be interested if someone could point out the more/most important areas/topics in real analysis so I know where to focus my time.

When I say most important, I mean the topics that are absolutely necessary for higher level progression to areas like functional analysis and topology.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider starting by reading some texts on solving proofs, if you don't have that robust a proof background. Here's a good thread to get you started:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655443/what-are-some-good-introductory-books-on-mathematical-proofs

Comment: almost any book of mathematics is a good reference to see how to make or write proofs. My recommendation is to start from the book *Understanding Analysis* of Abbott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For proof writing, here is a list of free, open-access book that handles how to do introductory proof-writing of many different calibers (many of these books are from the [Open-Textbook initiative](https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/)):

- [Book of Proof by Richard Hammack](https://www.people.vcu.edu/%7Erhammack/BookOfProof/)
- [Introduction to Proof via Inquiry-Based Learning by Dana C. Ernst](http://danaernst.com/IBL-IntroToProof/)
- [Introduction to Proof by Ron Taylor](http://jiblm.org/downloads/dlitem.php?id=56&category=jiblmjournal)
- [Mathematical Reasoning: Writing and Proof by Ted Sundstrom](https://www.tedsundstrom.com/mathematical-reasoning-writing-and-proof)
- [Notes for a Course on Proofs by Jacqueline A. Jensen-Vallin](http://www.jiblm.org/downloads/dlitem.php?id=88&category=jiblmjournal)

Here is a list of free, open-access books for Real Analysis:

- [A Primer of Real Analysis by Dan Sloughter](https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/textbooks/463)
- [Introduction to Real Analysis by Dana C. Ernst](https://danaernst.com/resources/free-and-open-source-textbooks/#:%7E:text=Introduction%20to%20Real%20Analysis%20by%20Dana%20C.%20Ernst)
- [Analysis by W. Ted Mahavier](http://www.jiblm.org/downloads/dlitem.php?id=66&category=jiblmjournal)
- [Measure, Integration & Real Analysis by Sheldon Axler](https://measure.axler.net/)
- A small list of [Classical Real Analysis Open-Access books](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/Free-Downloads.php)