# Any book on mathematical demonstration

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've found many books which treats of the theoretical and conceptual part of the mathematical demonstration, but now I'm searching for a book with a plenty of demonstration of mathematical proofs. Almost a "mathematical demonstration cookbook", with all sorts of solutions of problems like:

> prove that $10^n > n$, for every $n \geq 1$.

Anyone know something like it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Damn, thank you very much! Your answer in this second link probably has exactly what I'm looking for.
I have a doubt: what's the difference between heuristic and discrete mathematics? Please, can you answer it like "for dummies"?

Comment: I'll take a look, thank you.

Comment: By all these books that you recommended in your answers I think that _2000 Solved Problems_ and the _How to Think Like a Matheatician_ will be of great help. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I own *How to Think Like a Mathematician* and it is pretty good. It is similar, but I think slightly worse, than *How to  Prove It*. Regardless, it is probably worth checking out (especially if you have it in your university library).

Comment: Within mathematics, a heuristic is usually used as a synonym for a problem-solving strategy.

Discrete mathematics, on the other hand, is a very big chunk of mathematics. Although some high schools have courses labeled "discrete mathematics" which is usually geared towards weaker students, discrete mathematics certainly is not "for dummies". Both number theory and combinatorics are within the purview of discrete mathematics. For books on these topics, see the last two books on my list. A book like *How to Think Like a Mathematician* or *How to Prove It* would prepare you well for these.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic book about mathematical proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38854/basic-book-about-mathematical-proofs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure that you are an advanced high school student or beginning undergraduate. If you are not, please correct me. Here are some books you might want to look into. They are arranged in roughly in order of difficulty.

- **[Journey through Genius](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/014014739X)** by William Dunham
- **[How to Prove It](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995)** by Daniel Velleman
- [**Elementary Number Theory**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048646931X) by Underwood Dudley
- [**Proofs that Really Count**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883853337) by Arthur Benjamin and Jennifer Quinn

None of these books are cookbooks. I suspect that *How to Prove It* is most relevant to what you are looking for, but all four of the above books that will almost certainly pique your interest. It would probably be best that you look at a book like *How to Prove It* before looking at either of the last two books.

Comment: You're right, I'm a freshman on the physics course. I'm going to take a look on these books and if some of them seem help me I comment which one got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I took a look and I think this _How to Prove It_ will be better than a cookbook. Thanks for your help.