# Where do I best learn informal set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I want to learn math for machine learning, and I want to start with informal set theory.

I was reading 'naive set theory' (1960) by halmos, and it didn't seem to contain modern set notations.

If anyone knows a good material for learning informal set theory, please leave a comment.

That being said, I do not mind some rigor as long as it helps me with statistics, calculus, and other math fields used in machine learning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic book about mathematical proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38854/basic-book-about-mathematical-proofs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the book "[Book of Proof](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/BookOfProof.pdf)" of Richard Hammack; it have many diagrams and pics. The chapter about cardinals is very educational.

P.S.: Machine leaning is more about Linear Algebra and Probability Theory.

Comment: I started reading 'how to prove it' by velleman a while ago. How do you compare 'how to prove it' with 'book of proof'?

Comment: Both are very similar. I think the main difference is the style of the author. Read both: "How to prove it" has more verbosity, by other hand "Book of proof" has great diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already had a look at this: [Khan Academy: Set Theory](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/independent-dependent-probability/basic_set_operations/v/intersection-and-union-of-sets)

Comment: I'm not sure if https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/independent-dependent-probability/basic_set_operations is enough to enable me to write fluent set notations.