# resource to build very solid foundation?

Tags: book-recommendation

I want to build very solid foundation of modern mathematics.

resources and activities all I know so far are below. please advice me what to add and what to remove.
1. read Euclid's Elements (book)
2. watch math foundation youtube video

as you see, I have very poor knowledge on what I have to do.

Comment: I'd recommend learning some fairly basic set theory (e.g. from one of those "introduction to proofs" books; I used http://www.amazon.com/Transition-Advanced-Mathematics-Douglas-Smith/dp/0534399002/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1437830301&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=douglas+smith+introduction+to+proofs which was adequate) and then just...learning the math that interests you, rather than trying to work too hard on foundations.

Comment: (Cont.) The notion of building up all of mathematics from a common foundation is fraught with mathematical problems (encapsulated in the incompleteness theorems) and human problems (the resulting structures contain a huge amount of redundant information, such as whether $e \in \pi$).

Comment: I'm not sure what your level is, but eventually you should try Rudin's books on real and complex analysis.

Comment: You should start by familiarizing yourself with some basic concepts and proof techniques, for example by working through one of the books mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38854/basic-book-about-mathematical-proofs). Then you can choose a topic, like abstract algebra or calculus, and dive in (you can find many good book recommendations by searching this site, also consider looking at questions tagged [tag:reference-request]).