# Which books on proof-writing are stuitable for someone engaged in self-study?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, proof-writing, self-learning, book-recommendation

I want to learn how to read and write proofs. I only have basic pre-calculus skills. As I am preparing for my upcoming *calculus 1* course, I wanted to understand questions like

> Prove $\left|ab\right|=\left|a\right|\left|b\right|$ for any numbers $a$ and $b$.

These questions pop up in various *calculus* books and I need to understand them.

Any book recommendations?

Comment: Not a book recommendation, but if you answer a lot of the `calculus` questions here, your proof-writing skills will most likely improve.  :D

Comment: Here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/getting-better-at-proofs you can find several book recommendations to your question.

Comment: For better or for worse, most introductory calculus classes in the US at least tend to be proof light and computation heavy. Learning proofs is definitely something you'll need if you plan on studying math further, but for the most part the proofs you should see in Calculus shouldn't be bad.

Comment: Start on first order logic and set theory.

Comment: When writing a proof, write in complete, grammatical sentences. Justify everything. Especially do not omit any "implies" or "iff".  Practice this with proofs you already understand. Many students present a proof as a sequence of assertions  with no "connective tissue" explaining how they are related.

Comment: In addition to the great content linked by @MarvinF, I benefit most from the particular answer of Loop Space (when I remember to follow it). One thing missing, I would say, is building intuition about the topic through constructing examples. They can be numerical or qualitative, but developing some sort of intuition for a proof through constructing examples makes it 'stick' a lot better for me. A big part of the difficulty with understanding very abstract topics probably boils down from not being able to easily construct 'toy' examples to play with.

Comment: You can probably find a few similar questions on this site. Two examples I was able to find:
[Book covering introduction to mathematical proofs](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/606138) and
[Is there anything like "How to prove this"?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1750835)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic book about mathematical proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38854/basic-book-about-mathematical-proofs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just about to move into Calculus I, you don't need to worry much about the formal logic behind the mathematics. Proofs typically pop up first in a linear algebra or abstract algebra course sophomore or junior year at a university. Real analysis is where you need to worry about proving both integral and differential Calculus, but that's a class that you take after you finish the Calculus sequence anyway. Any facts in a basic single variable Calculus class should be easy to prove with information from your textbook, if you are even required to prove anything at all.

Comment: I cry sometimes over my obvious lack in ability to write good formal proofs.  :'(

Answer (score 0):

Precalculus Mathematics in a Nutshell: Geometry, Algebra, Trigonometry, George F. Simmons

Pre-calculus Demystified 2/E, Rhonda Huettenmueller

Comment: It has all the information on proofs on pre-calculus there is