# What is a good introduction to formal math as part of self-education?

Tags: self-learning

I have been trying to take a crack at a Number Theory book on an off for a while now, but I've never made it far, and I'm starting to think I am hampered by lack of education in formal mathematics.

My college education included discrete math, linear algebra, differential equations, and some engineering specific math.  Most of my work involved concrete problems, not abstract theorems and proofs.

I am looking for a book or lecture series that will help me on this so I can keep learning new math.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider [How to Prove It](https://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-Structured-Daniel-Velleman/dp/1108439535) by Daniel Velleman

Comment: Thank you, I purchased that book (2nd edition).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic book about mathematical proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38854/basic-book-about-mathematical-proofs)