# Looking for a book similar to Richard Hammack's "Book of Proof"

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, book-recommendation

I've almost read the "Book of Proof" by Richard Hammack and I fell in love with the way it has been written. I am looking forward to strengthen my knowledge in the field of **Discrete Mathematics**, so I'd like to have some books that extend the covered in Hammack's book.


To give you some words, that would point you in the direction I'd like to follow:

I am currently taking my Bachelor's degree in Software Engineering. I would consider myself as the kind of learner who wants to understand the concept behind everything, not just remember some formulas. I am studying mathematics really hard right now, because I'd like to become as great at problem solving as possible. Among my future goals is the very ambitious thing to contribute in a project, which aims to optimize the boring, repetitive things that humans are often attached to at their works.


(Books that include some *Graph Theory* and *Combinatorics* would win bonus points, however, please recommend a book even if it does not contain them.)

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. It could be useful to explain your motivations, long term goals.

Comment: @FShrike Thank you for the suggestion, my question is more explicit now

Comment: Doug West's *Introduction to Graph Theory* is a nice undergrad level text for Graph Theory. I personally quite like the writing style, and it has a plethora of nice problems at the end of each chapter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic book about mathematical proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38854/basic-book-about-mathematical-proofs)

Answer (score 1):

What book we used in my discrete math class was [Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and its Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073383090). Book goes through basic proofs, functions, and combinatorics just like what you would see in the Book of Proof. What I like in this book is it touches on graph theory, run-time analysis, and algorithms that you will see in software engineering. This book is made for a computer science student and does a good job of hitting all basic theory in computer science.

Answer (score 0):

I find combinatorics to be a field where there is little theory and the bulk of it is formulating the problem in the correct way. So I'd recommend Lovasz's *Combinatorial problems and exercises*.