# Introduction to proofs with a fair amount of hand-holding?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, proof-writing

Lately I've gotten a friend of mine interested in mathematics. He has no college-level education to speak of, but is well employed as a software engineer. So I feel he's competent to learn this stuff on his own.

He asked me recently if there was a 'mathematical' version of ["The Little Schemer"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262560992).

The point being, if there was an "introduction to proofs" book which took a more hand-holding approach. He's also expressed fondness for the [metamath project](http://us.metamath.org/).

However, metamath's proofs are obviously a bit *too* low level to learn anything serious.

At one point in our conversation, I mentioned the dependently typed programming language [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php), but I felt it's not quite as helpful until he at least gets some experience with [Haskell](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell) (for which the target audience of Agda is Haskell programmers, hence the similarity in syntax).

Anyone have any good suggestions on a book?

Comment: Somewhat tangential, but: it seems to me that your friend will greatly benefit from [Zeitz's book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0471789011).

Comment: As J.M. mentioned the book Zeitz: The Art and Craft of Problem Solving, it reminded me of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/getting-better-at-proofs Perhaps you can find something useful there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly on point, but since you mentioned the possibility that your friend might be learning Haskell, you could try "[The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths, and Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0954300696)".  Pretty good book, maybe a natural transition for your friend.

Answer (score 1):

May I humbly suggest my free [DC Proof](http://www.dcproof.com) program. It's not a book, but a software program. Although I think you are selling Metamath short -- check out the vast library of formal proofs at the site! -- my program is somewhat higher level and, in my opinion, much easier for the beginner to learn. It comes with a ten-part tutorial to introduce the user to the program and various methods of proof.